# Method for comparing text boxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need help, so I can compare the text from the text booths that are in these 3 groupboxes.

This is what my form looks like:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```vb
Private Sub frmCompareAdress_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim firstGroupBoxFields() As String = {TextBoxVorname1.Text, TextBoxName1.Text, TextBoxStrasse1.Text, TextBoxPLZ1.Text, TextBoxOrt1.Text, TextBoxTelefon1.Text}
    Dim secondGroupBoxFields() As String = {TextBoxVorname2.Text, TextBoxName2.Text, TextBoxStrasse2.Text, TextBoxPLZ2.Text, TextBoxOrt2.Text, TextBoxTelefon2.Text}
    Dim thirdGroupBoxFields() As String = {TextBoxVorname3.Text, TextBoxName3.Text, TextBoxStrasse3.Text,TextBoxNr3.Text, TextBoxPLZ3.Text, TextBoxOrt3.Text, TextBoxTelefon3.Text}

    ComparisonFieldsfirstGroupBoxFields, secondGroupBoxFields, thirdGroupBoxFields)
End Sub

Public Sub ComparisonFields(ByVal firstGBFields() As String, secondGBFields() As String, thirdGBFields() As String)
    Dim notCompareFileds = String.Join(", ", firstGBFields.Except(secondGBFields))

    'what to do next? I'm a little confused if I'm on the right track
End Sub
```

Now if, for example, the `textBox1Vorname.Text` is different from the `textBox2Vorname.Text` or `textBox3Vorname.Text`, I want to mark them in red.
I imagined it in a way, to compare as an array, and I put it in 3 array values from textboxes.

Can anyone help me further with this function?

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: `confused if I'm on the right track` - I don't think you are. I have no idea where you would go with that code.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you for asking, it's my attempt, I'm not sure it's the right way, if I'm wrong correct me, or how would you solve this?

Comment: @Mara read the answer from GSerg. That is a nice and clean solution to your problem?

Comment: @GSerg Hi, how could I add a check for the third textbox yet "textboxNr3" that when the type number is separated, it does not show a red error? should I understand the ColorAllRedIfNotSameText method to change? look at the picture in question what i posted now, it should be the same.

Comment: You cannot do that with this code. If you need to define sequences of textboxes that need to be considered as a whole when doing the match, then do so. E.g. `Public Shared Function HaveSameText(ParamArray controls() As IList(Of Control)) As Boolean : Dim s = String.Join(" ", controls(0).Select(Function(cc As Control) cc.Text)) : Return controls.All(Function(c) String.Join(" ", c.Select(Function(cc As Control) cc.Text)) = s) : End Function` and then `HaveSameText({TextBox1}, {TextBox2}, {TextBox3, TextBox4})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
Public Shared Function HaveSameText(ParamArray controls() As Control) As Boolean
    Return controls.All(Function(c) c.Text = controls(0).Text)
End Function

Public Shared Sub ColorAllRed(ParamArray controls() As Control)
    For Each c In controls
        c.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Next
End Sub

Public Shared Sub ColorAllRedIfNotSameText(ParamArray controls() As Control)
    If Not HaveSameText(controls) Then ColorAllRed(controls)
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub frmCompareAdress_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ColorAllRedIfNotSameText(TextBoxVorname1, TextBoxVorname2, TextBoxVorname3)
    ColorAllRedIfNotSameText(TextBoxName1, TextBoxName2, TextBoxName3)
    ColorAllRedIfNotSameText(TextBoxStrasse1, TextBoxStrasse2, TextBoxStrasse3)
    ColorAllRedIfNotSameText(TextBoxPLZ1, TextBoxPLZ2, TextBoxPLZ3)
    ColorAllRedIfNotSameText(TextBoxOrt1, TextBoxOrt2, TextBoxOrt3)
    ColorAllRedIfNotSameText(TextBoxTelefon1, TextBoxTelefon2, TextBoxTelefon3)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, how could I add a check for the third textbox yet "textboxNr3" that when the type number is separated, it does not show a red error? should I understand the ColorAllRedIfNotSameText method to change? look at the picture in question what i posted now, it should be the same.